# karma e2e testing framework, can it react to any mouse event?

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, mouseevent, karma-runner

I would like to know if it is possible that Karma test runner simulate any mouse event. In the official documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing), the only interesting event is "click" but a mouse can do really more than a simple "click" :  mouseenter, mouseleave, double-click, right-click and so on.

Thanks for advice,

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think E2E testing will support all of the mouse events. Obviously it will support `mouse-click` event, but I am not so sure about other events. Even a `mouse-over` event has got the testing issue. See the problem here;

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/kRjszANxQcg

Comment: Well, that is bad. Because the primary purpose of Karma testing is Front End testing, no matter of it is use for e2e testing or UI testing. And, in Front-End, testability of double-click, mouseover, etc, are not an option.